# Android Quiz App - Where should i place sqlite file?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm doing an android Quiz app...where it contains sqlite db with questions and answers...
So i want to retrieve questions/answers from the db...Where should i place my sqlite file in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm doing an android Quiz app...where it contains sqlite db with
>   questions and answers... So i want to retrieve questions/answers from
>   the db...Where should i place my sqlite file in the project?

It depends on more factors(size of database, character of records, performance requirements, ...)

If you know that your database won't be a little big, so you can save normally .db file into internal storage(assets folder, internal db folder). Main advantage is much more better security because on the other hand if you put .db file on SD card, there are for sure security issues.

So it's up to you what you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Your db file put in assets folder in project.

If you want to retreve it you can do it like this:

```
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(NAME);
```

where *myContext* is application context or context from activity and *NAME* varaible is name of the file.